# How can I set the display text for an Intent Filter?

Tags: android, intentfilter

I am creating an Intent Filter to share a bunch of media files with my App. I want to have a custom display text for the App icon, like "Add to favorites" but what it's displayed is the app name.

Here is my intent filter code in the Manifest

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg"/>
    <data android:mimeType="image/jpg"/>
    <data android:mimeType="image/png"/>
    <data android:mimeType="video/mp4"/>
    <data android:mimeType="video/wav"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Apps like Maps and Firefox have the text "Add to...", so I guess it can be done... but so far I haven't found any way.

[image: screenshot]

Appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the label for this intent-filter, like this:

```
<intent-filter android:icon="drawable resource"
               android:label="string resource"
               android:priority="integer" >
    . . .
</intent-filter>
```

Based on Android docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element

Comment: Yeah I just found it trying with the auto complete! I was looking for the `name` tag instead of the `label`... Thanks for sharing the documentation :)

Comment: Glad it helped! :)